# How to figure out the shard Id of an account or receipt using the RPC node API?

Tags: nearprotocol

I've looked through all the documentation but I cannot find a way to query in which shard a specific receipt is being executed. Is there no easy way of doing it?

There is one ugly way of doing it if the block of the receipt is known but it requires iterating through every receipt in every chunk in that block until found which is not very efficient and requires at least 4 RPC calls (for now with 4 shards).

Comment: shard details are hidden by design. there should be no advantage to knowing which shard an account lives on. can you clarify the goal here or the larger problem you're solving for?

Comment: @amgando I'm building an explorer and I want to create a nice transaction visualization feature that showcases how the transaction branches out into receipts and to which shards etc.

Answer (score 0):

The RPC indeed does not support that type of query. (It's an open-source project, you could open an issue for it and/or implement it: [github.com/near/nearcore/blob/master/chain/jsonrpc](https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/master/chain/jsonrpc).)

You might also find it useful to know the mapping from accounts to shards. For simple nightshade layout, it is defined in the [source code](https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/848c877d501f2c51c74a23be1aba196e28ea6d4b/core/primitives/src/shard_layout.rs#L156-L167) to split like this, using lexicographic sort order:

- shard 0 `account_id < "aurora"`
- shard 1 `account_id >= "aurora" &&  account_id < "aurora-0"`
- shard 2 `account_id >= "aurora-0" && account_id < "kkuuue2akv_1630967379.near"`
- shard 3: `account_id >= "kkuuue2akv_1630967379.near"`

As more phases of sharding are implemented, this can change. I think adding an RPC endpoint could be very valuable.